# how to set password for user at run time in chef

Tags: knife, chef-infra

How to set password for user creation in chef , at run time . instead of the encrypting mechanism using openssl and setting it in user resource in chef.

instead of the following method:

```
openssl passwd -1 "theplaintextpassword"
$1$JJsvHslV$szsCjVEroftprNn4JHtDi.
```

then setting it in user resource

```rb
user "random" do  
  supports :manage_home => true  
  comment "Random User"  
  uid 1234  
  gid "users"  
  home "/home/random"  
  shell "/bin/bash"  
  password "$1$JJsvHslV$szsCjVEroftprNn4JHtDi."  
end
```

Is there any alternative ..??

Comment: no.. my problem is not solved . still searching for solution

Comment: @mohan Are you sure my answer doesn't solve your problem? It generates the hash just like in your question.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could try generating the password ciphertext using Ruby in your cookbook:

```rb
require 'digest/sha2'

password = "pass@123"
salt = rand(36**8).to_s(36)
shadow_hash = password.crypt("$6$" + salt)
```

After running this, `shadow_hash` contains the following string:
`$6$vf1ehwzs$VAxaPBAeXjvEMboee.xbJgMOXlCrJ.eJDPkqP.16fGyAqjq1IDkh0OpEXFRo1W04G7tl02YMQz7dKmGKLVaRd/`

You can then use it in the `user` resource:

```rb
user "random" do  
  supports :manage_home => true  
  comment "Random User"  
  uid 1234  
  gid "users"  
  home "/home/random"  
  shell "/bin/bash"  
  password shadow_hash
end
```

From http://judepereira.com/blog/use-ruby-to-generate-your-shadow-password/

Comment: this wont work flyte .the problem with user resource is, its expects an encrypted data .. in password section..

Comment: That's what the top section of code does. It creates a hash of the password so that you can use the hashed string in the user resource.

Answer (score 1):

I haven't come across exactly what you are looking for yet, but the openssl cookbook comes pretty close.  With some tinkering you should be able to alter the method to accept string input then leveraging the unix-crypt library encrypt that string, or even just follow the pattern used in cookbook to make your own resource.

https://github.com/opscode-cookbooks/openssl

https://github.com/mogest/unix-crypt